# Como compilar a pasta do projeto inteira para ES5 usando babel.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-cordova, babel

Eu tenho um projeto HTML5 Cordova e eu preciso para fazer um hook antes de compilação para converter toda pasta projectos (www) para ES5 antes de compilar. É possível?

Estrutura

```
cordova/
    hooks/
    node_modules/
    platforms/
    plugins/
    www/
    config.xml
    icon.png
    splash.png
```

Comment: Estás em Node.js certo? Podes colocar o código do ficheiro que compila?

Comment: @Sergio O projeto é Cordova, não node. Mas tenho o node. Posso postar sim.

Comment: @Sergio Atualizei a pergunta com os diretórios.

Comment: Utilizo [Rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup) + [Bublé](https://buble.surge.sh/guide/#what-is-buble), vale a pena dar uma olhada, no meu caso a compilação é bem mais rápida.

Comment: @JonatasWalker Da pra converter diretório ou só arquivo esse Bumblé?

Comment: Como quiser, diretório ou arquivo ([exemplo](https://buble.surge.sh/guide/#compiling-multiple-files)), pessoalmente eu utilizo esse [modelo de projeto](https://github.com/jonataswalker/es6-sample-project).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu tenho algo parecido montado numa app em que estou a trabalhar. Aí misturo coisas de Browserify e Babel pois importo módulos que quero ter no cliente com npm. Mas a versão só Babel poderia ser assim:

```
"use strict";
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function babel(){
    return new Promise(resolve, reject){
        exec('babel --presets es2015 js --out-dir public/js', {
            cwd: __dirname + '/../'
        }, (err) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve();
        });
    });
}

module.exports = Promise.all([babel]);
```

Uso o Promise.all porque coloco nessa array mais coisas que preciso de compilar. Podes encadear com o `.then()` e chamar o compilador do córdova em seguida se estiveres a chamar via command line.

Na minha pasta estou a correr este módulo em `root/lib`, os ficheiros originais estão em `root/js` e estou a compilar todos os ficheiros de `.js` para `root/public/js`.

As dependencias são:

```
"babel-cli": "^6.4.5",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
```

Comment: boa! Como implementar isso em um hook do cordova para transpilar apenas em platforms/ios/assets?

Comment: @ropbla9 não conheço bem os mecanismos internos do cordova, sei que tem um "hook" central quando compila mas não domino. Isso seria uma boa nova pergunta que seria interessante ver respondida :) Dá uma olhada aqui: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/#configxml e podias testar colocar no `config.xml` um `<platform name="ios">` e defenir lá que script correr.

Comment: Sobre o Babel, não estou conseguindo usar pela CLI `Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory`. Poderia abrir privado?

Comment: @ropbla9 tens razão, esqueci, juntei agora as dependencias.