# Melhor forma de utilizar Module Pattern em javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou trabalhando em um projeto e utilizando o padrão ***Module Pattern*** no javascript do mesmo. Mas durante a implementação do projeto me surgiram algumas dúvidas.

**1º Dúvida:**

Existe alguma diferença entre as duas formas de utilização do *["Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)*

```
var modulo = (function() {
   //codigo
}());

var modulo = (function() {
   //codigo
})();
```

Ben Alman, autor do artigo: [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) implementa da primeira forma.

Ja Addy Osmani, autor do livro: [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) implementa da segunda forma.

Gostaria de saber se existe algum tipo de diferença técnica entre essas duas formas. Ou são apenas duas formas diferentes para se fazer a mesma coisa?

**2º Dúvida:**

Achei que seria interessante adicionar sub módulos dentro do meu módulo principal. Mas procurei em varios exemplos e links relacionados ao assunto e não encontrei nenhuma abordagem utilizando sub módulos. Então fiquei na dúvida, se devo ou não fazer isso. O uso de sub módulos pode me acarretar problemas futuros ou poluir o meu código?

Comment: alan, não existe problema algum em criar um modulo dentro de outro, inclusive é o que o [`Vanilla Masker `](https://github.com/BankFacil/vanilla-masker/blob/master/lib/vanilla-masker.js) faz. quando à desempenho, recomendações e diferença de execução nas chamadas IIFE, não existe, ficando apenas uma questão de estilo, porém o segundo modo é mais comum.

Comment: Estava utilizando a segunda forma msm! valeu! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em relação à tua primeira pergunta: ambas são equivalentes, é uma questão de preferência:

```
(function () { … })(); <-- a melhor (ver edit em baixo)
(function () { … }());
```

#### Edit:

meti-me à conversa no chat de JavaScript do SOen e no Reddit e referiram com razão que com a sintaxe de funções flexa, a segunda sintaxe não funciona(!). O que faz todo o sentido.

Exemplo:

```
(function (nr) { console.log(nr);})(1);
(function (nr) { console.log(nr);}(2));
(nr => console.log(nr))(3);
(nr => console.log(nr)(4));
```

o 4 nunca aparece...

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ymwj2c8z/

---

Em relação à tua segunda pergunta: usa IIFEs para limitar o escopo sempre que quiseres. A razão pela qual não se usa muito "submodulos" é porque o conceito de módulo (ou as boas práticas) é fazer cada módulo tão simples e re-utilizavel quanto possivel. Assim sendo um modulo nunca deve ficar tão grande que precise de submodulos. Mas não há mal nenhum em os criar.

Já agora, um à parte, acho que devias olhar para os modulos de Common JS ou melhor ainda da [nova sintaxe que aí vem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) com `import. Isso permite separar módulos em ficheiros e com um compilador como o Babel, Webpack ou Browserify podes converter isso em JavaScript "antigo" e correr no browser...

Comment: Entendi! Valeu pelas dicas. Vou dar uma lida nisso que você falou. :)

Comment: @alan Ótimo ter ajudado. Dá uma olhada a essa sintaxe nova, assim vais estar mais atualizado também. Até breve.

Comment: @alan fiz um edit importante... dá uma olhada de novo.

Comment: Beleza! valeu pela correção. Mas ainda não tinha visto "funções flexa". Vou dar uma estudada para entender o que elas fazem e como funcionam! ;)

Comment: @alan http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143399/129

Comment: Opa! Valeu! Só mais uma dúvida. Eu uso o sublime text. E acabei de instalar o package do Babel para ele. Mas parece que é um package para mudar apenas a sintaxe do código. Sabe me dizer se é possível a conversão do ES6 para o ES5 no sublime com o package do Babel?

Comment: @alan não conheço o sublime text... mas podes dar uma olhada aqui sobre como usar babel http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/146397/129 ou então converter online aqui: https://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: Blz! Valeu pelas dicas!

Comment: Sergio, sumiram os comentários com os links e dicas que você passou aqui. Você apagou?

Comment: @alan desculpa, queria deixar a página mais limpa. Mas se ainda são úteis deixo ficar. Coloquei de novo agora.

Comment: Opa! tinha um link q eu ainda n havia salvo! Mas agora salvei ele. Se quiser, pode limpar os comentários agora! ;)