# Como funciona essa função dentro de for?

Tags: javascript, funções

```
var del = document.getElementsByClassName("del");
if (del != null) {
    for (var i=0; i<del.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      var id_cliente = del[i].getAttribute('value');
      if (del[i].addEventListener) { del[i].addEventListener("click", function(){confirmaExclusao(id_cliente);}); }
      else if (del[i].attachEvent) { del[i].attachEvent("onclick", function(){confirmaExclusao(id_cliente);} ); }
        }
    )(i);
    }
}
```

Estou aprendendo a programar, e ao estudar este código que encontrei na internet, para deletar dados no Banco com Javascript e PHP me deparei com algo desconhecido pra mim até então. Dentro do `for` tem uma `function` que está entre parenteses, e ao terminar esta função, há a variável `i` do `for` entre parenteses >`)(i);`<

O que isso significa?

Dentro do meu programa, se eu retirar esta variável `(i)` ou retirar os parenteses da `function`, a função deixa de funcionar. Mas não consigo entender qual ou quais são os propósitos destes artefatos (função dentro de parenteses e `(i)`) no código Javascript.

Comment: Uma forma resumida de dizer oq é isso é: É uma função de auto execução. Ele cria um escopo fechado. Por isso q quando vc remove a variavel 'i' ela gera um erro. A um tempo atrás eu fiz uma pergunta semelhante, tem uns links bacana na minha pergunta e nas respostas. De uma olhada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/150775/melhor-forma-de-utilizar-module-pattern-em-javascript

Comment: Está respondido aqui no site mesmo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23785/

Comment: Obrigado galera, ambos me deram uma luz. Mas o que matou minha dúvida de fato foi este artigo que encontrei: https://goo.gl/CYsFsw.
Deixo ai como referência pra quem precisar futuramente.
Grande abraço!

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece nesse caso é o seguinte:

- Dentro do escopo do `for` existe a variável `i`, a qual é inicializada em `0` e incrementada com `+1` a cada "volta" que ocorre por causa do laço de repetição `for`
- Também dentro do escopo do `for` é criado uma *função anônima* que recebe o parâmetro que também foi chamado de `i` por simples acaso do destino, o qual, poderia se chamar qualquer coisa, poderia ser por exemplo `(funciontion(meuParametroMuitoLouco) { ...`
- A partir daí, a variável `i` dentro da *função anônima* passa a ser o parâmetro recebido na função, e não a variável `i` do `for`
- Sobre o comando entre parêntesis `(i)` ao final da *função anônima* o que ele faz é simplesmente executar a função que acabou de ser criada anonimamente passando a variável `i` criada na declaração do método `for`

O motivo de você não entender o que acontece é justamente pela escolha dos nomes de variáveis, o que torna muito confusa a separação visual do código, uma alternativa é alterar o nome da variável recebida como parâmetro dentro da função anônima, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
(function(indexParaDeletar) {
    var id_cliente = del[indexParaDeletar].getAttribute('value');
    if (del[indexParaDeletar].addEventListener) {
        del[indexParaDeletar].addEventListener("click",
            function() {
                confirmaExclusao(id_cliente);
            }
        );
    } else if (del[indexParaDeletar].attachEvent) {
        del[indexParaDeletar].attachEvent("onclick",
            function() {
                confirmaExclusao(id_cliente);
            }
        );
    }
})(i);
```

Outra alternativa é criar uma função e simplesmente chamá-la dentro do for, fazendo com que a função não seja anônima, o que tem o benefício de auxiliar no log de erro do console/browser, separar responsabilidades, melhorar legibilidade do código, etc, etc, etc, por exemplo:

```
function deletar(indexParaDeletar) {
    var id_cliente = del[indexParaDeletar].getAttribute('value');
    if (del[indexParaDeletar].addEventListener) {
        del[indexParaDeletar].addEventListener("click",
            function() {
                confirmaExclusao(id_cliente);
            }
        );
    } else if (del[indexParaDeletar].attachEvent) {
        del[indexParaDeletar].attachEvent("onclick",
            function() {
                confirmaExclusao(id_cliente);
            }
        );
    }
};

var del = document.getElementsByClassName("del");
if (del != null) {
    for (var i=0; i<del.length; i++) {
        deletar(i);
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Não sei se entendi sua pergunta, mas o objetivo de criar uma função separada, chamando de `deletar`, por exemplo, é justamente que ela não seja anônima, e nem que possua um escopo "fechado" dentro da execução do `for`, fazendo com que não seja reutilizável por outros métodos que estejam no mesmo "nível" do `for`. Sendo assim, função anônima é diferente de escopo fechado. Não sei se respondi tua pergunta. Se eu não consegui responder, consegue perguntar de outra maneira?

Comment: Acabei removendo para não complicar o espaço dos comentários, mas é basicamente o fiddle de exemplo que o @Sergio postou aqui : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23785/

Comment: Entendi, gostei da resposta do @Sergio, se tu quiser remover essa minha explicação aqui embaixo, pelo mesmo motivo que tu removeu a tua pergunta, por mim tudo bem :)

Answer (score 0):

O loop `for(;;)` não tem seu próprio escopo, e por conta disso essa função cria um novo escopo, re-generando o `i` como argumento.

O argumento `i` dentro do escopo dessa função permanecerá tendo o mesmo valor, enquanto o valor do `i` do escopo de fora vai sendo modificado pela ação do loop.

A intenção é poder usar o valor atual do `i` em escopos de dentro de loop, sem perder o mesmo valor quando esse escopo for executado, por exemplo:

```
var functions = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    (function(i){
        functions.push(function() {
            console.log(i);
        });
    })(i);

for (var fnc of functions)
    fnc();

// 0
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
```