# Fazer transpiling ES6 para ES5 usando o babel

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, babel, ecmascript-5

Tenho um arquivo package.json configurado para pegar todos os arquivos js de um diretório e juntá-los em um novo arquivo, fazendo transpiling para o ES5. Porém, ele está apenas criando um novo arquivo e unificando todos os arquivos js do diretório especificado. Ele não está convertendo para ES5. Não sei oque está faltando no arquivo package.json, se puderem me ajudar. Segue o código:

```
{
  "name": "farmafam",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "babel": {
    "presets": ["es2015"]
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "babel": "babel ../js/modulos/js-es6 --watch --out-file ../js/modulos/modulos.js"
  },
  "author": "KM2",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Duvido que o babel vá procurar os presets no package.json. Testa com `--presets es2015` no comando, ou seja: `"babel": "babel ../js/modulos/js-es6 --presets es2015 --watch --out-file ../js/modulos/modulos.js"`

Comment: Fiz a alteração e ele apresenta o seguinte erro: couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "..\\js\\modulos\\js-es6". :/

Comment: Talvez a ordem esteja errada, testa na consola diretamente `babel --presets es2015 --watch ../js/modulos/js-es6 ../js/modulos/modulos.js`. Eu tenho assim muitas vezes para compilar.

Comment: Ele diz que o es2015 não existe. Veja: "es2015 doesn't exist". Fiz vários testes aqui e descobri que quando eu jogo a pasta js-es6 para dentro da minha pasta npm com os modulos do babel instalados, e altero os caminhos no arquivo package.js. Funciona perfeitamente. Mas pensei em deixar separado por organização. Tipo, dentro da pasta npm ficará todos os módulos que eu for usar no projeto. Se misturar tudo fica meio bagunçado. :/

Comment: Não é uma resposta direta ao seu problema, mas tente utilizar o webpack como module bundler do babel que será bem mais tranquilo.
Se já utiliza segue abaixo 2 links de utilização do webpack com o babel. [link1](https://github.com/lramosduarte/ReactCordova) [link2](https://github.com/lramosduarte/ReactCordova)

Comment: @alan dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/146397/129 eu entretanto vou tentar simular o teu caso mais logo e ver consigo reproduzir o teu problema.

Comment: @alan você criou o arquivo `.babelrc` ?

Comment: O que resolveu o meu problema foi deixar os arquivos js-es6 junto com os modulos do babel e o package.json. Juntando eles ele compila direitinho. Mas quando separo ele só junta os js e n converte.

Comment: ficou assim: "babel": "babel js-es6 --watch --out-file modulos.js"